# Remove [bracket-shell] tag on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I created a tag for an application but I made a typo on the name. I created another tag with the correct name [brackets-shell](/questions/tagged/brackets-shell) but the mistyped tag [bracket-shell](/questions/tagged/bracket-shell) is still around. How can I get it removed?

Comment: With no questions attached to it, it'll be cleared out automatically.

Comment: No questions, it won't be around tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry. Tags that are not attached to any question get automatically removed every 24 hours.